# Should question authors be allowed to edit accepted answers into their questions?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

After a question is answered, is it acceptable to edit the question to include the answer?

For example, [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6215065/6), which I rolled back because it was harder to see what the original question was, and the answers did not make sense with the updated question.

Sometimes, instead of editing the original text of the question, they add new text to the end - "I did *X* and *Y* and *Z* and now it worked."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not acceptable to edit an answer into the question.  The answer should be posted as an answer.

If someone else edits the answer into the question it is entirely appropriate to roll it back.  However, when doing so, you should either ensure that there is already an answer that contains that information, post a new answer containing that information (and citing whomever authored the solution), or at the very least, post a comment explaining that the solution should be posted as an answer, so that the author can post the answer.

Comment: The linked revision is where *the author of the question* edited their implementation of the accepted answer into the question.

Comment: @immibis It is irrelevant whether the person editing in the solution is or is not the person that authored the question.  Do the same thing either way.